# The origin me is kind of cute

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Here's some fact about myself:

> -I am around 40 years old, though I was actually born in 1980.
>   -I twist your mind like you did to me.
>   -I come in many forms, thou the origin me is kind of *cute*.
>   -You might think i am divided by 27, but it's actually 26.

I am....?

Comment: I remark that Alex's other questions seem to have perfectly good English spelling and grammar. I guess, therefore, that the mistakes here ("thou" for "though", "I actually born" rather than "I was actually born", "I comes", etc.) are all deliberate. Alex, would you like to confirm this?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan oops, Friday Morning

Comment: Ah, OK. Sorry if I caused any offence.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan no offence at all, and you're quick!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are probably

> a Rubik cube.

I am around 40 years old, though I was actually born in 1980.

> Rubik's patent goes back to 1975, about 40 years ago. The first batch of exports actually called "Rubik's Cube" was in 1980.

I twist your mind like you did to me.

> It's kinda braintwisting, and you use it by "twisting" the faces relative to one another.

I come in many forms, thou the origin me is kind of cute.

> After the 3x3x3 cube, there were all kinds of variants of different shapes and sizes. I'm not quite sure why "the origin me is kind of cute" -- perhaps because *before* the Rubik 3x3x3 there was a smaller 2x2x2 that never really took off? Or because "cute" and "cube" are alike?

You might think i am divided by 27, but it's actually 26.

> It's a 3x3x3 cube and 3x3x3=27, but there isn't actually a centre piece: there are 26 "outer" cubelets that are held together by hidden protrusions in a rather clever way. (Though I think there are other mechanisms that *do* use a central piece somehow.)

Comment: Silly thought about the _cute_ clue: "Cubic root" (the origins of the cube) is a Spoonerism of "Rubik's cute" (my originator is cute).

Comment: That's ingenious!